Maximise $xyz$ such that $x+xy+xyz=1$, $y+yz+xyz=2$, $z+zx+xyz=4$

$x, y, z$ are real numbers which satisfy the following:
$$x + xy + xyz = 1$$
$$y + yz + xyz = 2$$
$$z + zx + xyz = 4$$
Then find the maximum value of $xyz$.

I tried adding and subtracting a few equations and substituting iteratively into the others which didn't work. Then I tried letting $xyz = k$ and trying to get stuff in terms of $k$ but I couldn't proceed with that either.

I directly solved the three equations. From first equation $$ z = \frac{1-x}{xy}-1 = \frac{1}{xy}-\frac{1}{y}-1$$, substituting this in the second equation, $$ y + y\left(\frac{1-x}{xy}-1 \right) + (1-x-xy)=2 \implies xy = \frac{1}{x}-x-2. $$
This implies $xyz = 1-x-xy = 3-\frac{1}{x}$ and $z= \frac{1-x}{\frac{1}{x}-x-2}-1 = \frac{3x-1}{1-x^2-2x}$. Substituting this in the third equation results in a cubic equation, $$\left(\frac{3x-1}{1-x^2-2x}\right)+\left(\frac{3x^2-x}{1-x^2-2x}\right)+\left(3-\frac{1}{x}\right)=4 \\ \implies \frac{3x^2+2x-1}{1-x^2-2x}-\frac{1}{x}=1 \implies  3x^2+2x-1-\frac{1}{x}+x+2 = 1-x^2-2x\\ \implies \boxed{4x^3+5x^2-1=0}.
 $$
This has three solutions $x = -1,-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{17}}{8},-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{17}}{8}$. The maximum of $xyz = 3-\frac{1}{x}$ is attained when $x=-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{17}}{8}$ and it is $$ \boxed{\frac{1}{2}(5+\sqrt{17})} $$

Wow! Such a simple approach

Label the three equations by (1), (2), and (3). Let $r := xyz$.
$(1)\times z - (3)$ gives $rz - 2z + 4 = 0$. Thus, $z = \frac{4}{2 - r}$.
$(2)\times x - (1)$ gives $rx - 3x + 1 = 0$. Thus, $x = \frac{1}{3-r}$.
$(3)\times y - (2)$ gives $ry - 5y + 2 = 0$. Thus, $y = \frac{2}{5 - r}$.
Thus, we have
$$r = xyz = \frac{4}{2 - r}\cdot\frac{1}{3-r}\cdot \frac{2}{5 - r},$$
$$r(2-r)(3-r)(5-r) = 8,$$
$$r(5-r) \cdot (2-r)(3-r) = 8,$$
$$(5r - r^2)(6 - 5r + r^2) = 8,$$
$$-(5r-r^2)^2 + 6(5r - r^2) = 8,$$
$$-(5r - r^2 - 2)(5r - r^2 - 4) = 0,$$
$$-(r-1)(r-4)(r^2 - 5r + 2) = 0,$$
which results in $r = 1, 4, \frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}, \frac{5-\sqrt{17}}{2}$.
When $r = \frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}$,
we have $x = \frac{1}{3-r}= \frac{-1 - \sqrt{17}}{8}$,
$y = \frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}$, and $z = \frac{1-\sqrt{17}}{2}$. It is feasible.
Thus, the maximum of $xyz$ is $\frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}$.
